# Как запросить разрешение на работу на экране блокировки Android?

Tags: java, android

Собственно, есть задача, запускать intent и показывать уведомление всплывающим сообщением даже если телефон заблокирован.
Удалось добиться запуска и корректной работы, если руками разрешить приложению работу на экране блокировку.

Теперь вот ищу, как можно программно запросить это разрешение?
Приложение корпоративное, сотрудники обязаны будут это разрешение принять. Но заставлять всех тащиться в настройки(а у всех они, естественно, в разных местах) ой как не хочется.

Comment: Вохможно, стоит смотреть в сторону [android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#DISABLE_KEYGUARD) и `WAKE_LOCK` там же. Делаю приложение для алярмов (как раз нужно, чтобы устройство просыпалось и поверх экрана блокировки отображалась активити), много подсмотрел [здесь](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android)